# SSH suddenly stopped working in git-bash on Windows 10

Tags: ssh, git-bash

I have been using git-bash in Windows 10 (Version 10.0.17134.1069) for a year now.

Since last week my SSH commands just hangs. It looks like this:

[image]

The process eats up 12% percent of the CPU and hangs. It also affects my GitHub pull and push. This is the path of my ssh `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` this is how it looks:

[image: ssh bash look]

I use Choco for program installation in Windows 10. Here is how is Git version:

[image: git version]

Comment: none yet :( lately I stop using ssh because of this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I´ve got the same issue with mysysgit 2.28.0 in Windows 10 2004 and I´ve opened a ticket at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2822 for further analyzation of this issue. I did some investigation with WinDbg and in my case it looks like this is related to ACL- or Hostname-Resolution.

As a workaround I´ve installed OpenSSH for Win32 (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) using the Chocolatey package manager (see https://chocolatey.org/packages/openssh/8.0.0.1 for more infos). Then I set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `"C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64\ssh.exe"`. After that git push/pull/etc. worked for me again.

**Addendum 20.10.2020**:

I found out that the problem was caused by the `epclient64.dll` which belongs to Citrix Workspace VPN client software. After uninstalling Citrix Workspace from my computer `ssh.exe` from mysysgit doesn't hang anymore. Furthermore I found out that the problem doesn't occur when I install the Citrix Worspace App from the Windows Store instead of using the Installer from the Citrix Download Site (https://www.citrix.com/de-de/downloads/workspace-app/windows/).

Comment: Up-voted.  I spent nearly half a day trying to figure this out and was getting nowhere.  Thanks for your post.  I too found that uninstalling Citrix Workspace App allowed 'git pull' (leveraging ssh.exe) to work again and that installing Citrix Workspace App through the Windows Store also allowed it to KEEP working the way it should.

Comment: this question craves for a solution. it was a recently installed Citrix software in my case too - but I cannot just uninstall it - ... in any case - I had made customizations to my .bashrc script for automatically starting ssh-agent on Windows according to multiple tutorials that are out there - a quickie to just make bash opening up again is to comment out everything in c"\Users\[username]\.bashrc - in case you do have that file. - a better answer would be about how to setup ssh-agent again without messing with Citrix

Comment: the tutorial that I mention above is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404272/running-ssh-agent-when-starting-git-bash-on-windows

Comment: is there any chance https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/win10-internet-connection-problem/59141108-4477-4124-928b-3cc8ea63a322 is related to this citrix issue ? my win10 is still having this problem.

Comment: I have the same issue, but only have "Citrix Receiver" installed. There's no epclient64.dll on my computer.